# Windows API Call CB_SELECTSTRING

Tags: c#, wcf, winapi

We have a C# 2012 WCF service that is interacting with a desktop application that is built in VB6 no less and are having issues with a drop down selection using Windows API calls.

The way the application works when you are actually working within it is that you select an entry in a drop down box first. Then enter information in text boxes below it. You select another entry in the drop down box, the fields reset to blank text boxes. The code behind on the downstream application associates the text box information with the selection in the drop down. That is way that particular app works.

Our problem is automating this process. We use Win32 API calls to set information in the drop down using the following:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, [Out] int wParam, string lParam);

// Actual call to the downstream app.
SendMessage(hWnd, (int)CB_SELECTSTRING, 0, strValue);
```

The problem is when we try to set the second value in the drop down box. The text boxes are not being reset. We have tried using the following calls as well:

```
SendMessage(hWnd, (int)CB_SELECTSTRING, -1, strValue); 
SendMessage(hWnd, (int)CB_SETCURSEL, 0, strValue); 
SendMessage(hWnd, (int)CB_SETCURSEL, -1, strValue);
```

None of these messages are accomplishing the task. We need the call to simulate the Selected Index Changed event. Are we not using the right piece here? Or do we need to send a message to the parent to fire off that event?

I looked through our solution and did not find CBN_SELCHANGE anywhere or any API call that would send that to the parent.

Any ideas here folks?

Comment: May not be related but your declaration of sendmessage looks fishy http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html

Comment: Would be helpful to see code that retrieves hwnd of combobox in the vb6 app

Comment: These messages cannot work as-is, the string pointer that's passed is only valid in your process, not the vb6 process.  Lots and lots more code is required to make the string pointer valid.  Don't go there, use an UI Automation library instead.

Comment: Ok ... update to the situation. We did some testing with different ideas and found that using SendInput to send the drop down box just the letter A resets the controls. However, sending the drop down box the full string we want selected does not work as each character sent changes the selection to the first entry with that character as its first letter. So the question is why does SendInput fire off the selection changed event when SendMessage does not and can we get something like SendMessage to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that the notification CBN_SELCHANGE should be fired in this case. Once you change something in the combobox programmatically, it will be easier for you to change whatever else on the form from the next line of your code. Doing same thing threw the notification only complicates the code. Think as if you are writing the code of this form.

Once you are able to access the hWnd of the combobox, you maybe should update your entry fields as well using the same SendMessage.

Other approach - send the CBN_SELCHANGE yourself. There is nothing against that. This is simply a message.

The CB_SETCURSEL is not using the LPARAM. You should pass 0 there.

You should also recheck how .Net marshalls your string. I am not sure this will be so simple. To verify this build your own small dll, check definition to `DllImport("myUser32.dll")` and put a breakpoint in the debugger at the entry of your dummy `SendMessage`. You will see what comes to the native code.

Comment: I apologize for that confusion. I copied and pasted and hit submit before I correctly edited those messages.